# How can I count the no occurences within 30, 60, 90 day periods?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I have all of the 90-day activities on other sheet and I'm trying to count the people who have no activity and sorty it via 30, 60, and 90 days

I have tried to count the number of those who have activities but can't do on the no-activity people.

Comment: Your Question is lacking a lot of information. Not possible to answer. Consider to show a sample file

Comment: Surely you'll be able to filter and sort, but please share more information as some sample data to understand and provide better feedback

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75122840/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: If you can get a count of people who have activities, you can subtract that from the total number of people to get the number of people who have no activities.